# rake db:migrate error in digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

```
[root@centos-512mb-nyc3-01 dc]# rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RDF::DC
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdf-2.2.3/lib/rdf.rb:65:in `const_missing'
/root/dc/app/models/concerns/work_metadata.rb:10:in `block in <module:WorkMetadata>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
/root/dc/app/models/generic_work.rb:5:in `include'
/root/dc/app/models/generic_work.rb:5:in `<class:GenericWork>'
/root/dc/app/models/generic_work.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curation_concerns-1.6.3/app/models/curation_concerns/classify_concern.rb:41:in `to_class'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curation_concerns-1.6.3/app/models/curation_concerns/classify_concern.rb:14:in `block in all_curation_concern_classes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curation_concerns-1.6.3/app/models/curation_concerns/classify_concern.rb:14:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curation_concerns-1.6.3/app/models/curation_concerns/classify_concern.rb:14:in `all_curation_concern_classes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/curation_concerns-1.6.3/app/models/concerns/curation_concerns/nested_works.rb:7:in `block in <module:NestedWorks>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `include'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `block in append_features'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `append_features'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sufia-7.0.0/app/models/batch_upload_item.rb:5:in `include'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sufia-7.0.0/app/models/batch_upload_item.rb:5:in `<class:BatchUploadItem>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sufia-7.0.0/app/models/batch_upload_item.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/root/dc/config/initializers/overrides.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/root/dc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Post the code that uses rdf in your rails app.  I would guess that you are calling some method incorrectly and failing to pass a required argument, hence a constant named RDF::DC in the gem does not get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The version of rdf you are using doesnt have

```
RDF::DC
```

you need to use

```
RDF::Vocab::DC
```

or use version below 2.0

https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf/issues/293